# Why is my ECDSA fingerprint encoded with MD5 when it is shown as a fingerprint?

Tags: ssh, openssh

In my `/etc/ssh` folder there are several different SSH keys (which list different algorithms such as MD5 or ECDSA).

The one used by default is the ECDSA but when it shows its fingerprint (when I am logging in) the fingerprint is encoded with MD5 encryption (and colon delineated)

Why isn't it shown as encoded with ECDSA?

Comment: MD5 is not a form of encryption. It's a hashing algorithm sometimes used to generate fingerprints.

Comment: The publickey algorithms supported by OpenSSH and used for host keys in `/etc/ssh` and user keys in `~/.ssh` are rsa, dsa, ecdsa, and ed25519 depending on version. (There are actually two variants of rsa; the obsolete SSHv1 variant is named just `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_key` or `~/.ssh/identity`.) The fingerprint for ANY key type used to be computed with MD5 and displayed in hex with colons; in recent versions of OpenSSH it is computed with SHA256 and displayed in base64 with no colons, but you can get the older form with `ssh-keygen -l -E md5`.

Comment: @txtechhelp the fingerprint mentioned in the question, isn't literally the fingerprint of the author, but the fingerprint of the key being used....

Comment: @Ramhound, HA!! That's what I get for browsing during a fit of insomnia :) removed the comment so no other caffeine deprived confusion can ensue

Answer (score 2):

MD5 is hash and ECDSA is key pair. Totally different things used for totally different tasks.

Your ECDSA key have unique fingerprint created using MD5 hash. Similar way all the RSA or DSA have MD5 fingerprints that identify them.